# GAS - discovering information at runtime

Tags: google-apps-script

Since the GAS documentation actually sucks, I thought I might try to at least discover information about the parameters that are passed to even handlers.  This trivial example shows what am I trying to do.

MyGui is built using the Gui-builder.
It contains a button - btn, which has a click callback - btn_click
It also contains a TextArea - txtArea1

simples

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  app.add(app.loadComponent("MyGui"));
  return app;
}

function btn_click(e) {

  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var ta = app.getElementById('txtArea1');

  if(!e)
  {
    ta.setText('null object');
  }
  else
  {
    ta.setText(e.toDebugString());
  }

  return app;
}
```

Silly me !  I assumed that since the documentation repeated states that the GAS components are built upon GWT, and GWT being Java based, EVERYTHING is a java.lang.Object, that I should be able to call toDebugString() to find at least some information about the object passed into the handler function.

Sorry, I am very close to giving up on using GAS, it's just a toy right now, and I don't have time to play, I actually have work to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client side of UiApp is GWT widgets. Nowhere have we stated that the server side is made up of GWT Java objects (it isn't), nor would that even make sense based on how they are documented to work. The server objects are no more than references to the client objects - references that you can use to associate commands with, which then get shipped down to the client. There is no debug information to be had, because the server "widgets" have no information other than the id of the client widget they are storing up commands for.

Comment: Ah. OK, fundamental misunderstanding on my part, I guess.  Thanks

Comment: UiApp is definitely a rapid dev tool rather than a 100% fully featured toolkit. If you want much finer control of UI code, use jQuery inside of HtmlService.

Answer (score 1):

I remember a library [SmartDebug](https://script.google.com/macros/library/d/MHDTOOt9dn-ViHNtwfsIfJ5lu8m0d5vP9/8) which allows logging of objects in a ui. Add the library and try this:

```
function doGet() {
var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  SmartDebug.enable(true);
  SmartDebug.addLogWidgetToApplication();
  app.add(app.loadComponent("MyGui"));
  return app;
}

function btn_click(e) {
   var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  if(!e) {
    SmartDebug.logMessage('null');
  } else {
    SmartDebug.logObject(e,'event');
  }
  return app;
}
```

here's what I got:

```
11:19:55: event.parameter.clientY: 161
11:19:55: event.parameter.clientX: 143
11:19:55: event.parameter.eventType: click
11:19:55: event.parameter.ctrl: false
11:19:55: event.parameter.meta: false
11:19:56: event.parameter.source: Button1
11:19:56: event.parameter.button: 1
11:19:56: event.parameter.alt: false
11:19:56: event.parameter.screenY: 270
11:19:57: event.parameter.screenX: 143
11:19:57: event.parameter.y: 18
11:19:57: event.parameter.shift: false
11:19:57: event.parameter.x: 92
```

Comment: Interesting.  It appears that e is being passed to SmartLogger as type 'event'.  Where is that type documented ?

What happens if you pass it as type 'object' ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you associated in the GUI Builder a callback element to the button? If you put the button in a FormPanel all the fields of the FormPanel are submitted as parameters, if it's a simple button you have to add callback elements to get as event parameters that is in the GUI Builder the small white box under the event to fire on the event.

Comment: Yes, I understand how to generate a callback, and the callback is called, however, that is not my question.  

The question is, how to know what is available in the parameter - this is not documented anywhere (that I can find, anyway).  

Furthermore, why doesn't the supplied code, above, work.  e.toDebugString fails.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the standard Javascript [toSource](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tosource_date.asp) method to debug some objects. If you debug the default example code you get given when creating a new web-app script this is what toSource gives you:

({parameter:{clientY:"22", clientX:"17", eventType:"click", ctrl:"false", meta:"false", source:"u29169455861", button:"1", alt:"false", screenY:"148", screenX:"381", y:"18", shift:"false", x:"13"}})